# Using regex to extract substrings

Tags: python, regex

I have a string:

```
s = r'"url" : "a", "meta": "b", "url" : "c"'
```

What I want is to capture the substring `url: ...` up to the `,`, so the expected output is a list:

```
[r'"url" : "a"', r'"url" : "b"']
```

I am using:

```
re.findall(r'("url"):(.*),', s)
```

but all it does is to return the entire string. Is there something i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last "," was beeing matched due to a greedy search, (.*?) is non greedy.
Also the last comma is optional so that needs to be ignored if not present

```
import re

s = r'"url":"a","meta":"b","url":"c"'

print(re.findall(r'("url"):"(.*?)",?', s))
```

Answer (score 1):

You must escape the `,` to avoid including the comma inside the group. Try this:

```
re.findall(r'(("url" :[^,]*),*)', s)
```